# how to get all anchor tags of page and add class?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, anchor

how to get all anchor tag of page and add one class to mailto (eg. `mailto:example@example.com`) and another to web link (eg. `http://example.com`) ?

output expected :

```
<a href="mailto:example@example.com" class="class1">
<a href="http://example.com" class="class2">
```

Comment: Pravat Maskey's edit drastically changed the nature of Sujeet's original question. What's up with that? I'm rolling it back, since the edit does not reflect what the OP actually asked for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to find tag in same document do like

```
$('a[href^="mailto:"]').addClass('class1');
$('a:not([href^="http:"])').addClass('class2');
```

to find in iframe do like

```
jQuery("a[href^='mailto:']",jQuery("#myiframe")[0].contentDocument).addClass('class1');
jQuery("a:not([href^='http:'])",jQuery("#myiframe")[0].contentDocument).addClass('class2');
```

Comment: You need to use quotes around those attribute values in CSS: http://mothereff.in/unquoted-attributes#mailto%3A This will error when using the Selectors API, or when using some versions of Sizzle/jQuery.

Comment: This isn't what the OP actually asked for.

Answer (score 11):

```
$('a[href^="mailto:"]').addClass('class1');
$('a:not([href^="mailto:"])').addClass('class2');​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/3t2MQ/2/

**Update** Use `:not()` instead of `[href^="http"]`.

Comment: You need to use quotes around those attribute values in CSS: http://mothereff.in/unquoted-attributes#mailto%3A

Answer (score 2):

You can use this JQuery to get a collection of anchor elements:

```
var elements = $("a");
```

from there you can loop through each and check the href value:

```
elements.each(function(){
   var a = $(this);
   if(a.attr("href").indexOf("mailto:") == 0){
      a.addClass("MailToClass");
   }
   else{
      a.addClass("HttpClass");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each($('a'), function(k, v) {
        var href = $(v).attr('href');
        if (href.indexOf('mailto') != -1)
            $(v).addClass('class1');
        else
            $(v).addClass('class2');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
$('a[href^="mailto:"]').addClass('class1'); //This line adds a class to any href starting with mailto
$('a[href^="http"]').addClass('class2'); //This line adds a class to any link starting with http
```

Comment: You need to use quotes around those attribute values in CSS: http://mothereff.in/unquoted-attributes#mailto%3A This will error when using the Selectors API, or when using some versions of Sizzle/jQuery.

Comment: @Learner The other poster must have finished writing their answer before me... Don't jump to conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('a[href^="mailto').each(function(){
   $(this).addClass('sth')
})
```

Comment: indeed, this is probably the best answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery `.each()` function to loop through all the anchor elements and check the `href` so you know which class to add.

**Example**

```
$('a').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('href') == 'mailto:example@example.com'){
        $(this).addClass('class1');
    }
    else if($(this).attr('href') == 'http://example.com'){
        $(this).addClass('class2');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('href').indexOf('mailto:') == 0) {//mailto link
   $(this).addClass('class1')
  }
  else {
   $(this).addClass('class2')
  }
 });
```